# Sentences with "If X need to be ..."

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, sentence-structure

I wrote:

> Therefore, if a variable **needs to be set** by this value, a post-assignment is used.

The auto grammar detection of Office word suggested me

> Therefore, if a variable **need to be set** by this value, a post-assignment is used.

As I checked google, I found similar constructions like:

> If a section or a folder need to be set as private ...

What is the structure here, it seems the *need* doesn't refer to *variable*.

Comment: It should be "needs." Microsoft Office is not a good option to check grammar. Microsoft office is kinda dumb. On google, did you use quotation marks? and what did you type, in the first place? Click [me](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+variable+need+to+be%2Ca+variable+needs+to+be&year_start=1940&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20variable%20need%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20variable%20needs%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Usernew, thanks, I also think I should say *if a variable needs to be set **with** this value*... right?

Comment: A variable is assigned (with) a value or set to a value. The value doesn't do the assignment or the setting, so **by** is not the right preposition.

Comment: @Ahmad Umm...yes. Like TRomano said. I think "by" is also correct. I even checked on [googlebooks](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22set+by+this+value%22). I got more results on "[by](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22set+by+this+value%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22set+by+the+value%22)" than "[with](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22set+by+this+value%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22set+with+the+value%22)."

Comment: @Usernew, thanks, However, Tromano suggested [set to the value](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22set+by+this+value%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22set+to+the+value%22), and [assigned with the value](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22set+by+this+value%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22assigned+with+the+value%22).

Answer (score 1):

It should be **needs** for a singular item, or **need** for plural items. In this case **a variable** is singular so **needs** is correct.

Note your second example has a plural: **section or folder**. If were just one section or one folder then it would need to be **needs** too, like so:

> If a folder needs to be set as private...